# Average values of integer lists and dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, average

Is there a way of calculating the average of the values of two or more lists or even dictionaries?

This is what I came up with:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
listb = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

listavg = [0]*5
count = 0
for i in lista:
    listavg[count] = (i + listb[count]) / 2
    count += 1

print(listavg)
```

---

```
[3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

---

But what if I have 100 lists? And what if those lists are inside dictionaries like these:

```
{'A': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'B': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'C': [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'D': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 'E': [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], 'F': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], 'G': [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6], 'H': [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], 'I': [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8], 'J': [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]}
```

P.S. the length of the list is always the same.

---

EDIT: Important note is that I want the average of each index, not the average of the list.

Comment: Maybe you can make your lists to tuple of column length vector then using #[statistics.mean](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a list comprehension:

```
>>> [sum(l)/len(l) for l in zip(*list_dict.values())]
[4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5]
```

Comment: Wow, one line of code for my problem :D.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()` to get a tuple of each element grouped together index-wise from the input lists, and use `sum()` to add them together:

```
>>> def averages(*lists):
    return [sum(els) / len(els) for els in zip(*lists)]

>>> averages([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
[3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]
listb = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
lists = lista + listb
average = sum(lists) / len(lists)
```

I think this works fine.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my problem.

Comment: I was unsure of the implication of your question. Could you please give me both the code used and the desired output. This will help me, as well as others, to help you.

Comment: I have already found a solution thanks to @Rawing and Christian Dean. What I wanted was to get the average values comparing 2 lists' indexes. I included an example output of what I was looking for.